# lidbgx move objects from right to left

Tags: java, android, libgdx

```
batch.begin();

    batch.draw(tr_background, 0, 0, 3024, 1443);

    batch.draw(tr_ball, x, 110, 100, 100);

    batch.end();

    x = x + 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    if(x > camera.viewportWidth)
        x = -100;
```

it moves left to right then back to start position. How to move it right to left when `tr_ball` reaches at the right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ball speed variable for the class

```
float ballSpeed = 100;
```

Then flip it when the ball goes past the end of the screen. So, replacing your code after `batch.end()` above:

```
x += ballSpeed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

if (x >= camera.viewportWidth - 100) {
    x = camera.viewportWidth; // prevent overshooting
    ballSpeed *= -1;
} else if (x <= 0) {
    x = 0; // prevent overshooting
    ballSpeed *= -1;
}
```

This code assumes your camera is positioned with 0 on the left edge of the screen. Also the 100 is the ball width. That should really be a constant (static final float) since you'll be using it in multiple places in your code.

Comment: hey bro, thank you!!!!!! When it reachs left side again, it dont back to right. How to do it? Thank you again

Comment: I should have used `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<`, but it's unlikely that would be the cause since we're comparing floats, not ints. I don't see any other errors in my code. Maybe you can post your version so I can see if there's something wrong there.

Comment: I just updated it to take care of the case where there is kind of a long frame right before the ball reaches the end, and then can never bounce out of that region. It now shifts the ball back to the exact edge when it overshoots.